# Durandal.js / Knockout.js - Is it possible to return to originating click event after compositionComplete?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal, promise

So I am working on a durandal/knockout app where I click a button defined like so:

```
<button class="addNote" data-bind="click: function () { addNote($parent); }">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
```

My "addNote" handler goes off and composes a new view/model (which is basically just a big bound textarea) and inserts them into the screen.  At the end of that composition (in the compositionComplete method) I set the focus on the newly created textarea using knockout's hasFocus binding.

```
var compositionComplete = function (view, parent) {
    setFocus(true);
};

<textarea data-bind="value: note, hasFocus: setFocus" autofocus></textarea>
```

This is working very nicely because my users are able to press the "Add" button, and start typing a note without having to place their cursor into the <textarea> field.  EXCEPT on mobile devices  (I've tried iPads, iPhones, Nexus tablets, surfaces, samsung s3/s4, windows phones).

The focus is actually set on the <textarea> (I can tell because the focused style we have is applied) but the user still needs to click/tap on the <textarea> to get the soft keyboard to open.  After lots of googling and several failed attempts, I found some people noting success when they set the focus on the <textarea> from the originating click event.

Being fairly new to durandal/knockout, and an average js coder at best, I am wondering if there is a way to have compositionComplete run (so that I know the <textarea> has been loaded) to my click event which could then set the focus? Like a string of promises or some sort of chain of events?  My theory is that if I could wait at the click event to set the focus, the keyboard might just pop up.

```
<button class="addNote" data-bind="click: function () { someEvent($parent); }">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>

var someEvent = function (parent) {
    addNote(parent);
    //wait here until compositionComplete fires and then setFocus(true);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be just a timing issue although it just shows up on mobile devices.

So I'd start using Durandal's  `composition.addBindingHandler('hasFocus');` http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Interacting-with-the-DOM.html capability to ensure that `hasfocus` fires after the view has been composed.

**Plan b)** leverage Durandal's event system http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Leveraging-Publish-Subscribe.html. In that case you might want to come up with a dfiddle https://github.com/dFiddle/dFiddle-2.0 with a minimal implementation that demonstrates the issue. That way it might be easier to spot where's the best place to trigger the events.

Answer (score 0):

The path of least resistance is probably just to trigger a `click` event on the textarea.